# How can I debug an HTTP POST sent from my iPhone app?

Tags: objective-c, http

I'm using the following code to upload an image to my server:

```
// Dictionary that holds post parameters. You can set your post parameters that your server accepts or programmed to accept.
NSMutableDictionary* _params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
DataManager *manager = [DataManager sharedManager];
[_params setObject:[manager token] forKey:@"token"];
[_params setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[manager site_id]] forKey:@"site"];

NSString *BoundaryConstant = @"----------V2ymHFg03ehbqgZCaKO6jy";
NSString* FileParamConstant = @"image";
NSURL* requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mysite.com/api/upload/"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
[request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
[request setTimeoutInterval:30];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", BoundaryConstant];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

for (NSString *param in _params) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [_params objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(saveImage, 1.0);
if (imageData) {
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"image.jpg\"\r\n", FileParamConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", BoundaryConstant] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSLog(@"%@",body);

NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]];
NSLog(@"Sending request with length: %@",postLength);
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];

[request setURL:requestURL];
 NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Watching my server logs as I try and upload, I don't get a lot of information:

```
82.132.x.x - - [06/Feb/2013:15:37:45 +0000] "-" 400 0 "-" "-"
```

Compare this with another query from the same app:

```
82.132.x.x - - [06/Feb/2013:15:36:13 +0000] "GET /api/sites/?token=blah HTTP/1.1" 200 269 "-" "My%20App/1.0 CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/13.0.0"
```

How can I figure out what is going wrong? Clearly the request is malformed in some way, causing the error 400. Is there some tool I can use to inspect it?

Comment: I don't see `Content-Length:` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @paulbailey 4 lines from the bottom...

Comment: D'oh! I'd second using Charles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wireshark should allow you to inspect what's being sent / received.http://www.wireshark.org/download.html

Comment: Since I can simply dump the HTTP body straight out of my app, this seems like overkill. Is there somewhere where I can just paste the data and get feedback about why it might be failing?

Comment: Filters for wireshark, make it easier to filter out what you're not interested in - http://www.lovemytool.com/blog/2010/04/top-10-wireshark-filters-by-chris-greer.html

Answer (score 1):

Try [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)... It's friendlier than wireshark to use (not free... but they have a trial) http://www.charlesproxy.com/

Comment: I agree, it cuts out a lot of the noise in wireshark if you're looking to do some topical monitoring.

Comment: Is it possible to use this on the phone or my (headless Ubuntu) server?

Comment: Can't use on either... but if you're running this in the iPhone simulator you should be able to run it on your Mac. On your ubuntu server you could either monitor your incoming http requests if you have logging enabled `tail -f /path/to/access_log` or using tcp dump see http://serverfault.com/questions/84750/monitoring-http-traffic-using-tcpdump

Comment: I can't use the simulator without writing a bunch of code, since this app is uploading photos.

Comment: Just install Charles on your dev machine, then set that machine as the HTTP proxy on your phone. I've used that very workflow to debug network traffic from an App Store app that wasn't mine.